# Convert from Array[((String, String), Double)] to Array[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])]

Tags: scala

This is an array of comparisons between two string and their numberical value :

```
  val initialType: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array((("a", "a"), 0), (("a", "b"), 3), (("a", "c"), 2),
    (("d", "b"), 2), (("d", "c"), 1), (("d", "d"), 0))
```

The converted array contains a sorted sub array
  The lone String "a" and "d" are the header labels for each each comparison :

```
  val convertedType: Array[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])] = Array(("a", Array((("a", "a"), 0.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0), (("a", "b"), 3.0))),
    ("d", Array((("d", "d"), 0.0), (("d", "c"), 1.0), (("d", "b"), 2.0))))
```

Here is what I have so far :

```
object Convert extends App {

  val initialType: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array((("a", "a"), 0), (("a", "b"), 3), (("a", "c"), 2),
    (("d", "b"), 2), (("d", "c"), 1), (("d", "d"), 0))

  val numberUniqueUsers = initialType.map(m => m._1._1).distinct.size
  val grouped: Iterator[Array[((String, String), Double)]] = initialType.grouped(numberUniqueUsers)

  val sortedGroups : Iterator[Array[((String, String), Double)]] = grouped.map(m => m.sortBy(s => s._2))

  sortedGroups.foreach(g => g.foreach(println))

}
```

Which prints :

```
((a,a),0.0)
((a,b),3.0)
((a,c),2.0)
((d,b),2.0)
((d,d),0.0)
((d,c),1.0)
```

How to convert this to `Array[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])]` ?

Comment: just use initialType.groupBy(_._1._1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialType.groupBy(_._1._1).toArray
```

example

```
@ val initialType: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array((("a", "a"), 0.0), (("a", "b"), 3.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0),
  (("d", "b"), 2.0), (("d", "c"), 1.0), (("d", "d"), 0.0))
initialType: Array[((String, String), Double)] =
  Array((("a", "a"), 0.0), (("a", "b"), 3.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0), (("d", "b"), 2.0), (("d", "c"), 1.0), (("d", "d"), 0.0))

@ initialType.groupBy(_._1._1).toArray
res3: Array[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])] =
  Array(("d", Array((("d", "b"), 2.0), (("d", "c"), 1.0), (("d", "d"), 0.0))), ("a", Array((("a", "a"), 0.0), (("a", "b"), 3.0), (("a", "c"), 2.0))))
```

Comment: thanks, modified slightly to sort : initialType.groupBy(_._1._1).toArray.map(m => (m._1 , m._2.sortBy(s => s._2)))